# How do I style part of the pseudo element content: "..."

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am inserting a FontAwesome icon along with some text from the data attribute in a div pseudo element:

```
<div data-date="Mar 01, 2016"></div>

div:before {
  content: "\f073" attr(data-date);
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cn0vhns9/

Now what I want is to increase the size of the icon and put the text right under it with some margin. While putting the text content under the icon seems achievable (if I fix the width of the pseudo element), I can't think of the way to increase the size of the icon without increasing the size of the text content as well. Any ideas?

Comment: in this case, you can not! but let see what other say.

Comment: You can't do it with css, but you may use :after with different style. Or you may increase the icon font size in a font editor app!

Comment: Actually it is possible, give me a second.

Comment: Sorry, the :after tag is already taken. I don't want to add any content to the div element as well (cause it has plenty).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible even in your case. Please, see the [**updated fiddle** at https://jsfiddle.net/cn0vhns9/3/](https://jsfiddle.net/cn0vhns9/3/). You will have to style the icon as a pseudo-element (`::first-letter`, or alternatively `:first-letter` with just a single semicolon for compatibility reasons).

My answer only demonstartes the problem with different font-size.

**CSS**

```
div:before {
  content: "\f073" attr(data-date);
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}

div::first-letter {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-date="Mar 01, 2016">

</div>
```

However, I consider this solution to be a bit hacky. Most likely I would separate the icon and the date and place each of them into a separate HTML tag if possible.

Comment: I like this solution! Why don't you recommend it?

Comment: @Deka87 Well, first of all I am not sure what is the browser support - have not checked it. Second thing is that the HTML should be semantic. I would rather put the icon and the text in two different HTML tags which nicely decouples the two parts of the information and gives you much better styling possibilities.

Comment: Actually it is a good solution (semantics aside). Browser support for `::first-letter` is pretty good if I am not wrong.

Comment: Seems like even IE8 supports the :first-letter pseudo element. I think this is the best answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Deka87, well, if even IE8 supports it I guess you are good to go :D.  You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use another pseudo element:

```
div:before {
content: "\f073" ;
font-family: "FontAwesome", sans-serif;
padding: 20px;
color: black;
font-size:2em;
}
div:after 
{
content:attr(data-date);
display:block;
border-top:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: The after tag is aleady in use, should have mentioned that, sorry.